# How do I make Google Sheets sort my words correctly

Tags: spreadsheet

I'm working on SEO and I've gathered a huge list of keywords (around 2000).

What I want to do is this:
Make sheets look at the 2000 keywords and get every word with <whatever I fill in>

**Example:**

Pears are awesome

Apples are awesome

Pineapples are awesome and great

Apples are awesome and great

Pears are awesome and great

I want all the results showing for "pears"

**So sheets spits out:**

Pears are awesome and great

Pears are awesome

Bonus points if it moves them so I don't have to manually remove the keywords from the list.

It was a long time since I've coded, I tried, but to no avail.

And after hours of messing around with the search, find and other randomly not working commands, I thought it was time to search for help.

I also really feel like this is a stupid question for some reason, but I just couldn't find it for the life of me.

Comment: What have you tried already? Why don't you just put a filter in the header and filter for "Text contains"?

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your problem, a simple SORT function should resolve your problem.

=SORT({Data};{Column to sort by};{is ascending})

Where {Data} is the area where you have your "raw data" (one or several columns), {Column to sort by} pretty much says it, but make shure to white is at f.x. {A:A}, and not just {A}. {is ascending} should be either {true} or {false}, for ascending or descending sorting.

Your SORT function can also contain functions, like this:

SORT(A:C; ISBLANK(A:A); true; VALUE(A:A); true; B:B; false; C:C; true)

(isblank to avoid sorting blank cells on top, and value to make sure the sheets sorts column A by numerical value, and not alphabetically (so 2 comes before 10 even though 2 comes after 1)

I hope this helped :)